# Несколько скрытых блоков

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Сейчас работает вот так:

```
<a class="qr" id="toggler" onclick="facechange('#QR'); return false">Show Qr</a> <a class="qr" id="toggler" onclick="facechange('#rules'); return false">Read rules</a>
```

и

```
function facechange(objName) {
    if ($(objName).css('display') == 'none') {
        $(objName).animate({
            height: 'show'
        }, 400);
    } else {
        $(objName).animate({
            height: 'hide'
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Все работает - все хорошо. Но вот вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы блок, который в данный момент открыт скрывался, если у нас открывается другой блок?

Comment: зачем используете onclick="" если у вас jquery ?

Comment: регистр для facechange() используете разный

Comment: параметр должен называться не objName а selector и он явно будет криво работать, если ему передать facechange('body')

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
</style>

через data-area-id указывают ID блока, который надо показать

<a class="area-toggler" data-area-id="qr">Show Qr</a>
<a class="area-toggler" data-area-id="rules">Read rules</a>

классом hidden помечаю блоки, которые не видно
<div class="area hidden" id="qr">QR</div>
<div class="area hidden" id="rules">RULES</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a.area-toggler').on('click',function(){
            // найти все блоки, у которых нет класса hidden (то есть они видимые) и спрятать их
        $('div.area:not(.hidden)').animate({height: 'hide'}, 200).addClass('hidden');

            // после этого показать тот, который связан с кликнутой ссылкой и поставить ему класс "hidden" (то есть его теперь не видно)
    var areaId = $(this).data('area-id');
    $('#' + areaId).animate({height: 'show'}, 400).removeClass('hidden');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: добавил комментарии - может так ответ понятнее